# Es obligatorio tener un SSL en una web simple donde no se solicitan datos a los usuarios?

Tags: hosting, ssl, dominio, certificado-ssl

hace poco me cambie de hosting y en el nuevo parece que no me incluyen certificado SSL para todos los sitios alojados, y hace una semana cuando intente entrar en uno me aparecia el mensaje de google chrome informando que el sitio web es inseguro por lo que tuve que hacer un certificado SSL en ZeroSSL e instalarlo en ese dominio, el problema es que tengo que cargar uno nuevo cada 3 meses.

Hay alguna manera de que no figure que el sitio web es inseguro sin tener que actualizar el SSL cada 3 meses?

El sitio web es muy basico, solo con algo de informacion pero no vendo ni pido datos a los usuarios.

Gracias!

Comment: como alternativa [letsencrypt usa validación ACME](https://letsencrypt.org/es/docs/client-options/) para la renovación por lo cual implementar [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) es bastante sencillo

Comment: Y además, Google penaliza en su posicionamiento web a las páginas http, con lo que ese es otro motivo más para tener instalado un certificado...

Comment: Ese hosting que dices... ¿que panel de control tienen?  ¿cpanel, plesk, vestacp, etc?  La mayoria de ellos incluyen SSL gratis que se autorenueva cada 3 meses, y si no quieren ponertelo será por su política de ventas/negocio.

Answer (score 1):

respodiendo a tu pregunta, es una buena práctica y un elemento de seguridad no menor e importante usar `SSL` en tu sitio o aplicacion web, por mas siemple que sea. Puedes revisar en `cloudflare` por ssl gratuitos.